# Play 2.1 Java Promise

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I have an application migrated from Play 2.0.4 to 2.1. When compile in Play 2.1, this error was thrown out.

```
[error] /Users/XXX/app/controllers/SomePost.java:93: cannot find symbol
[error] symbol  : constructor Promise(org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode)
[error] location: class play.libs.F.Promise<org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode>
[error]         return new Promise<ObjectNode>(result);
```

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it. Previous, it was like this:

```
return new Promise<ObjectNode>(result);
```

After I changed to this, it worked!

```
Future<ObjectNode> ft = Futures.successful(result);
return new Promise<ObjectNode>(ft);
```